# Random seed c# - How to generate same sequence of numbers for debug

Tags: c#, random

I am writing a cards game, and need to draw random cards from pile. I am using Random and Random.Next(..) for that.
Now I want to debug my application, and want to be able to reproduce certain scenarios by using the same Random sequence.
Can anyone help...? I couldn't find an answer over several searches.
Thanks.

Comment: Use a fixed seed while creating Random class.

Comment: You may wish to use a `#if DEBUG` tag too

Answer (score 11):

Use the overload of the [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor which accepts a seed value

```
static Random r = new Random(0);
```

This will produce the same sequence of pseudorandom numbers across every execution.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to seed your random number generator. Assuming you're using `System.Random`, use

`Random r = new Random(<some integer>);`

which starts the sequence at `<some integer>`.

*But an important note here: you will need to research your random number generator carefully.  Else it will be possible to decipher your sequence which will make playing your game unintentionally profitable for an astute user. I doubt you'll be using `Random` once you pass to production.* (Technically it's possible to decipher a linear congruential sequence - which is what C# uses - in a little over three drawings.)

Answer (score 1):

Create a `System.Random` instance with the same seed:

```
Random random = new System.Random(1337);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the same seed in Random constructor. That guarantee you that Next() will give the same results. For example

```
Random randomGen1 = new Random(5);

Random randomGen2 = new Random(5);

int r1 = randomGen1.Next();
int r2 = ramdomGen2.Next();

if(r1 == r2)
{
 Console.WriteLine("Great success!!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a bit of overkill for this case (using a seed will give you repeatability) but a good shape for dealing with dependencies over which you do not have full control is to wrap the dependency and access it through an interface.  This will allow you to swap in a version that gives specified behaviour for unit testing/ debugging.

**e.g.**

```
public interface IRandom {
    int Get();
}

public class DefaultRandom : IRandom {
    private readonly Random random;

    public DefaultRandom() {
        random = new Random();
    }

    public int Get() {
        return random.Next();
    }
}

public class TestRandom : IRandom {

    private readonly List<int> numbers;
    private int top;

    public TestRandom() {
        numbers = new List<int> {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21};
        top = 0;
    }

    public int Get() {
        return (top >= numbers.Count)
                ? 0
                : numbers[top++];
    }
}
```

One of the nice aspects of this method is that you can use specific values (say, to test edge cases) which might be hard to generate using a fixed seed value.